# how do i open file with application like emacs,vim, TextMate in golang?

Tags: go

How do I open a file within an application like emacs, vim, TextMate in golang?

```
cmd := exec.Command("open", "-a", "/usr/bin/vim", "/var/www/index.php")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

or

```
cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/vim", "/var/www/index.php")
cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

I found both of the above cannot work, is there any good solution?

Comment: your second code example is working for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This definitely works - what errors are you getting ?

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
)

func main() {
    cmd := exec.Command("/usr/bin/vim", "/var/www/index.php")
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    if err := cmd.Run(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```